# How best can I retrieve all comments for a given chat room in Firebase on the web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a real time firebase app with chatrooms and comments. A comment belongs to a single chatroom and a chatroom can have many comments.  I'd like retrieve just the comments for a given room, but right now I'm only able to get all of them.

Every time a comment is saved, I also save its id to the room to which it belongs. That way, every room has a list of its comment ids. I can retrieve a chatroom's list of child comment ids using `chatRooms/${id}/commentIds`.

```
// data structure is basically like this:
chatRooms: {
    ROOMID123: {
        title: "Room A",
        commentIds: {
            COMMENTIDABC: true,
            COMMENTIDXYZ: true
        }
    }
},
comments: {
    COMMENTIDABC: {
        message: "some message",
        parentRoomId: ROOMID123
    },
    COMMENTIDXYZ: {
        message: "Another message",
        parentRoomId: ROOMID123
    }
}
```

I can get the comment ids for a given room, based on the room's id, like this:

```
firebase.database().ref(`chatRooms/${chatRoomId}/commentIds`).on('value', 
    snapshot => {
        const commentsObject = snapshot.val();
        const commentIdsList = Object.keys(commentsObject);
    });
```

Would it be better for me to

a) use that list of commentIds to retrieve only the comments for a given room? If so, what query should I use?

b) use the chatRoom's id to retrieve every comment with a matching `parentRoomId`? If so, I don't know how to do this despite reading through the docs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose a third option: store the comments for each chat room in a separate parent node. So something like:

```
commentsPerRoom: {
  ROOMID123: {
    COMMENTIDABC: {
        message: "some message",
    },
    COMMENTIDXYZ: {
        message: "Another message",
    }
  }
}
```

With the above structure you can retrieve the comments for a specific room with a single direct lookup:

```
firebase.database().ref(`commentsPerRoom/${chatRoomId}`).on('value',
```

Reasons I'd use this data structure over your current one:

- Storing the comments as a single list means you'd have to query that list. And while Firebase Realtime Database scales quite well, querying for data is always going to have scalability limits. That's why the above data structure allows a direct look up, instead of requiring a query.
- Loading the individual comments through the comment IDs is definitely also possible, and not nearly as slow as some developers think due to the fact that [Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786). But it seems unneeded here, since the comments already have a strong 1:n association with the room they belong to. Each comment only belongs to one room, so you might as well model that relationship in how you structure the data, and save yourself all the lookups.
- Retrieving comments for a specific room is by far the most common use-case, and this data structure allows that use-case the most efficiently.

Comment: I like that suggestion. Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Just so I can learn, do you mind giving me an example of how I would load individual comments through the comment IDs? I'm not sure how I would structure that kind of query.

Comment: Loop over the IDs and then do ``firebase.database().ref(`comments/${commentId}`).once('value', ...`` for each